# run two php scripts with conflicting class names

Tags: php

I want to start from a php script two other php scripts. Unfortunately, these two scripts define both a class with the same name.
I tried with

```
<?php
// master_script.php
require(script_one.php);
require(script_two.php);
?>
```

script_one.php:

```
<?php
// script_one.php
class foo{
public function do_something(){
}
}

$foo = new foo();
$foo->do_something();
    
?>
```

script_two.php

```
<?php
// script_two.php
class foo{
public function do_something_two(){
}
}

$foo = new foo();
$foo->do_something_two();

?>
```

I can I force php to forget everything it previously loaded? or can I execute another php script differently?

Comment: You should use namespaces to keep scripts from conflicting.

Comment: @Barmar does this really help, when I call in the second script the function by its original name?

Comment: Yes. Within a namespace you can refer to classes and funtions with unqualified names.

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

Comment: @Barmar I am not sure whether this is possible without a massive change of my scripts. I added at the beginning of both scripts a namespace, but now I get errors that classes that are loaded by these scripts cannot be found

Comment: Are you putting the namespace statements in the master script or the included scripts?

Comment: @Barmar in the included scripts, but the included scripts also load other scripts where classes are defined.

Comment: Assuming all of your code wasn't using a namespace before, when you put `foo` into a namespace, and classes it was accessing (besides the other `foo`) will need to be prefixed with a forward slash, so `new \blah()`. You can also mess around with `use` in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

you should use from extending like this:

```
<?php
// script_one.php
class fooOne{
public function do_something(){
}
}
?>
```

and

```
<?php
// script_two.php
class foo extends fooOne{
public function do_something_two(){
}
}
?>
```

and

```
<?php
// master_script.php
require(script_one.php);
require(script_two.php);

$foo = new foo();
$foo->do_something(); // this calls func from script_one.php (fooOne Class)
$foo->do_something_two(); // this calls func from script_two.php (foo Class)

?>
```

Comment: okay apparently my minimal example was too minimal. my two script that I call are more complex than just this. Both script load classes from other files and unfortunately, some classes have the same name, but are not equal. I was looking for an easy modification to run both. However, it seems like there is no such way.